# Shifting text section to the right

Tags: wrapfigure, text-manipulation

I have a large picture on the left side of the page and text referring to the picture on the right side. My problem is that the code as it is atm makes the text overlap the figure. It looks like this:

```
\newpage    
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.5\textwidth}    
\vspace{-2cm}     
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{pics/dummy.png}    
\vspace{-100cm}    
\end{wrapfigure}    
\section{Test}    
text referring to picture    
text referring to picture    
text referring to picture    
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: @Andreas You need to post code that is compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Your problem may depend on the document class you're using, the packages you've loaded, etc. Without this information, your question is unlikely to be answered.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should remove `\vspace{-100cm}`, `\vspace{-2cm}` and `[width=0.8\textwidth]`.

Instead of the last one you should put `0.8` to the `wrapfigure` environment settings.